# Ajax with jQuery UI dialog not working

Tags: plugins, jquery, database, ajax, jquery-ui

I am trying to update my custom database table when changes are made in a dialog box. The script for the dialog box and ajax call is as follows -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$("td > span").click(function(){

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var message = "message"+id;
    var content = jQuery("#"+message).text();
    var $dialog = $("<div></div>").html("<textarea style='width:99%; height:90%' class='popup-content'>"+content+"</textarea>").dialog({
        height: 400,
        width: 400,
        title: 'My Data',
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        dialogClass: 'wp-dialog',
        buttons: {
            "Save": function(){
                $("#"+message).html($(".popup-content").val());
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: script_data.admin_ajax,
                    data: {
                        action: "feedmng_update",
                        feed_id: id
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    $dialog.dialog("open");
  });
});
```

The above script works all well but for the Ajax part. The above code is a separate javascript file which I even enqueue in my php file. The following is the Ajax call related code to update database having the id passed during the Ajax call -

```
function __construct(){    
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_feedmng_update', array( &$this, 'feedmng_update' ) );
  add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'feedmng_load_scripts' ) );
}

function feedmng_update(){

    global $wpdb;
    $feedid = $_REQUEST["feed_id"];
    $wpdb->update( $wpdb->feedmanager, array( 'message' => "New data" ), array( 'id',$feedid ) );
}

function feedmng_load_scripts(){

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-dialog' );
    wp_enqueue_style (  'wp-jquery-ui-dialog' );
    wp_register_script( 'feedmng-popup', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/feed-manager/mypopup.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-dialog' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'feedmng-popup' );
    wp_localize_script( 'feedmng-popup', 'script_data', array( 'admin_ajax' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
```

**EDIT**
Added the following to the script, console shows "Success"

```
success: function(){
console.log("Success");
}
```

My table name is wp_feedmanager and I am trying to update it's 'message' column. But it just wont update ? Any suggestions what should be done ?

**For future reference -**

The problem was here - 
The third parameter of update query should be **array( 'id' => $feedid )**
Also the EDIT regarding tablename suggested by Milo needs to be included !

Comment: You have a type in your `$wpdn->feedmanager`.  It should be `$wpdb->feedmanager`.

Comment: Ok, I corrected that too...that aint a problem. Still not working.

Comment: Are you receiving a success in your console when you run the ajax?

Comment: `url: "admin-ajax.php"` is almost certainly not the right path to `admin-ajax.php`

Comment: @josh Receiving no success

Comment: +1 Milo!  Try changing `admin_ajax.php` to `ajaxurl`.

Comment: Tried this too...no success yet !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your javascript and ajax action code are otherwise correct, target `admin-ajax.php` with the correct path by [localizing](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) your enqueued script:

```
wp_localize_script(
    'your_script_handle',
    'script_data',
    array( 'admin_ajax' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) )
);
```

Then in your javascript, reference that URL with:

```
url: script_data.admin_ajax
```

**EDIT-**

ah, missed this the first time: `$wpdb->feedmanager` isn't set unless you've explicitly set it somewhere. `$wpdb->table_name` only works for native tables, as those member vars are hard-coded directly into the wpdb class. change it to a string `'wp_feedmanager'`.

also note that the `wp_` table prefix can be (and should be) changed via `wp-config.php`, use `$wpdb->prefix` to make your code more portable:

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'feedmanager';
```

Comment: Tried what you suggested...no success yet !

Comment: edit your question and add your current code, including your script enqueue code. use your browser's error console to check for errors and/or 404s.

Comment: Added more relevant code

Comment: see edit above.

Comment: Thanx Milo, but still no success.

Comment: you'll have to do some more in-depth debugging then- hardcode an update that's not within an ajax request and get that working, echo every var at every stage to make sure it's what you expect, get a simple ajax request without the update code working, etc..

Comment: Yes that seems to be the case now...

Comment: Wow...it finally works....
Well the error was here - the third parameter of update query should be array( 'id' => $feedid )